# Slick - Disable slider going to first and last slide

Tags: jquery, slider, swipe, slick.js

I need to customize the slick slider so that it starts from slide 2 and goes upto slide n-1. As it will not an auto-scroll, user can only swipe it left or right to the slides.

For example, we have 5 slides `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.
When page loads, first visible slide should be number `2`. If user tries to swipe right, he should not be able to go to slide `1`.

If user is at `n-1` slide and he tries to swipe left, he should not be able to go to last slide.

Just to make my objective more clear, here's what I am trying to do. I am showing half part of next and previous slides in it. So, when user lands on the page, he will see half part of `slide 1`, full `slide 2` and half part of `slide 3`.

I tried to find the solution a lot but no luck.

Comment: After doing some digging into the slick [docs](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), I don't think you can disable swiping on specific slides (using the library settings), to achieve this, you could use custom javascript code.

Comment: Yes, I have guessed that. Can you please suggest me the technique to do so using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `slidesToShow: 3` and `centerMode: true`. Then using css reduce margins on the sides that are causing the other slides to be hidden to cover parts of slides 1 and 3.

This will cause slide 2 to be centered and slides 1 and 3 to be partially shown.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem. Here is how I did it.

[image]

In slick, I used `slidesToShow: 3` without `centerMode`

Now, here is the jQuery Magic.

1. When we set slidesToShow equals 3, the slider visible area divides into 3 blocks. But our requirement is 1/2 + 1 + 1/2 blocks should be visible on screen
2. So, we increase slider visible width to `windowWidth + (windowWidth / 2)`
3. The slider main container width is set to 100% of screen with `overflow: hidden;`
4. Now, you will see only 2 slides on screen. To make it our way, we translate the slider on x axis to `-(windowWidth / 4)`

That's all. Here is the jQuery code.

```
$(".slider").slick({
    arrows:         false,
    autoplay:       false,
    autoplaySpeed:  4500,
    infinite:       false,
    pauseOnFocus:   false,
    pauseOnHover:   false,
    slidesToShow:   3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
});
var winWdth = $(window).width();
var sliderWidth = winWdth + (winWdth / 2);
$('.slider').width(sliderWidth);
$('.slider').css({'transform' : 'translateX(-' + winWdth / 4 + 'px)'});
```

Comment: This will hide your first and last slide. Which is not the case all slides need to appear if scrolltoslide is 1.